# Formula dependency for Homebrew

Tags: homebrew

Similar to X11 in the example [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Formula-Cookbook.md#specifying-other-formulae-as-dependencies), I want to assure Inkscape is installed.

Having `depends_on :inkscape` in my formula does however throw

```
Error: kws: Unsupported special dependency :inkscape
```

Is it not possible or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

X11 is a special kind of dependency in Homebrew and Inkscape is not a standard formula but a cask.

If you want to depends on the cask Inkscape, you have to use the following syntax:

```
depends_on cask: 'inkscape'
```

Read [Brew Formula: How can I define cask and external dependencies?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/449138/brew-formula-how-can-i-define-cask-and-external-dependencies/459806#459806) for a complete answer.

Comment: Well I tried that before, and what I got was `Error: kws: Unsupported special dependency :cask`

Comment: I'm not sure you can depend on a cask from a standard formula.

Comment: I thought the same. However, in the cookbook they explicitly state that you can depend on other system-wide installations. I guess that only works for selected libs

Comment: Double check that you use `cask:` and not `:cask`.

Comment: Only works if you are making a cask, standard formulas cannot depend on a cask